# Monoids in categories

Tags: category-theory

[image]

Question: what are $\lambda:1\times M\to M$ and $\rho:M\times 1\to M$? My guess is they are projections from the product to its right and left factor respectively. Is it correct? Moreover, is it possible to prove that they are isomorphisms?

EDIT: Let $\sigma:M\to 1$ be the unique morphism to $1$. Then $\tau:=\langle \sigma, 1_M\rangle:M\to 1\times M$ is such that $\lambda\tau=1_M$. This provides a right inverse to $\lambda$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition given here is an instantiation of the more general concept of [monoid in a monoidal category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoid+in+a+monoidal+category), instantiated in a cartesian (monoidal) category. Hence, the $\lambda$ and $\rho$ are the right and left unitors respectively, which correspond to the two projections in a cartesian category, as you indicate. It is possible to prove that projections $X \times 1 \to X$ and $1 \times X \to X$ are isomorphisms using the universal properties of the terminal object and cartesian product. I think this is a helpful exercise, but can provide hints if you're not sure where to start.

Comment: I've edited, can't find left inverse.

Comment: To show that two morphisms are equal using universal properties, we can show that they are *both* mediating morphisms for the universal property: uniqueness tells us these are then equal. In our case, we want to show that $\langle !, 1_M\rangle : 1 \times M \to 1 \times M$ is equal to the identity. Does this help?

Comment: Yes, I got it thank you